# Change icon on Bootstrap Collapse with Jquery

Tags: jquery, icons

I have this accordion that I made:

```
<div id="accordion">
 <div class="card">
   <h5 class="mb-0">
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i> <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne" style="color: black;">Here's the question </button></h5>
 <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
  <div class="card-body">
    Here's the collapse answer!
 </div>
   </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm a noobie in Jquery so how my jquery code would look like to achive the following: when it's collapsed, I want to change fas fa-chevron-down with fas fa-chevron-up.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap Accordian - After icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53951093/bootstrap-accordian-after-icons)

Answer (score 3):

For this, you can take care of your work with CSS.

Using the bootstrap panel, you can perform font-awesome definitions when the accordion is turned on or off, as in the following example :

```
.panel-title>a {


display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.panel-title>a:after {
    content: "\f078";
    /* fa-chevron-down */
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}

.panel-title>a[aria-expanded="true"]:after {
    content: "\f077";
    /* fa-chevron-up */
}
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css');
.panel-title>a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.panel-title>a:after {
  content: "\f078";
  /* fa-chevron-down */
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.panel-title>a[aria-expanded="true"]:after {
  content: "\f077";
  /* fa-chevron-up */
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading-1">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-1">
          Item 1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse-1" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-1">
      <div class="panel-body">

        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion-1" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading-1-1">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-1" href="#collapse-1-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-1-1">
                  Item 1 > 1
                </a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse-1-1" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-1-1">
              <div class="panel-body">

                <div class="panel-group" id="accordion-1-1" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading-1-1-1">
                      <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-1-1" href="#collapse-1-1-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-1-1-1">
                            Item 1 > 1 > 1
                          </a>
                      </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse-1-1-1" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-1-1-1">
                      <div class="panel-body">
                        Text 1 > 1 > 1
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading-1-1-2">
                      <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-1-1" href="#collapse-1-1-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-1-1-2">
                            Item 1 > 1 > 2
                          </a>
                      </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse-1-1-2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-1-1-2">
                      <div class="panel-body">
                        Text 1 > 1 > 2
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading-1-1-3">
                      <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-1-1" href="#collapse-1-1-3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-1-1-3">
                            Item 1 > 1 > 3
                          </a>
                      </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse-1-1-3" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-1-1-3">
                      <div class="panel-body">
                        Text 1 > 1 > 3
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading-1-2">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-1" href="#collapse-1-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-1-2">
                  Item 1 > 2
                </a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse-1-2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-1-2">
              <div class="panel-body">
                Text 1 > 2
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading-2">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-2">
          Item 2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse-2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-2">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Text 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading-3">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-3">
          Item 3
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse-3" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-3">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Text 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can toogle the fa class from 'fa-chevron-down'  to 'fa-chevron-up'

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$('.sort-chevron').toggleClass('fa-chevron-down fa-chevron-up');">Sort By <i class="fa fa-chevron-down sort-chevron"></i> </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for similar solution.

```js
 $('.panel-collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    $(this).siblings('.panel-       heading').addClass('active');
  });

  $('.panel-collapse').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
    $(this).siblings('.panel-heading').removeClass('active');
  });
```

```css
body{
  padding:50px;
  background:#fff;
}
.wrapper{
  width:70%;
}
@media(max-width:992px){
 .wrapper{
  width:100%;
} 
}
.panel-heading {
  padding: 0;
 border:0;
}
.panel-title>a, .panel-title>a:active{
 display:block;
 padding:15px;
  color:#555;
  font-size:16px;
  font-weight:bold;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 letter-spacing:1px;
  word-spacing:3px;
 text-decoration:none;
}
.panel-heading  a:before {
   font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
   content: "\e114";
   float: right;
   transition: all 0.5s;
}
.panel-heading.active a:before {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
 transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class = "container">

  
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
  
</div> <!-- end container -->

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

JS

```
let wrapper = $('#accordion');
$('.btn-link').on('click', function () {
let status = $(this).attr('aria-expanded'); // code is useless here. Just to check if collapse open or close
  wrapper.find('.fa-chevron-down').removeClass('fa-chevron-down').addClass('fa-chevron-up');
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="accordion">
 <div class="card">
   <h5 class="mb-0">
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i> <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne" style="color: black;">Here's the question </button></h5>
 <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
  <div class="card-body">
    Here's the collapse answer!
 </div>
   </div>
    </div>
</div>
```